Can a Householder reflector (transform) be extended to a product of vectors?
Can a Householder reflector (transform) be extended to a product of vectors?  Specifically, say we have two routines:
$$\begin{align}
h_m(i,x) =& (\alpha,v)\textrm{ where } x-\alpha\langle x,v\rangle v = \pm\|x\|e_i\\
h_n(j,y) =& (\beta,w)\textrm{ where } y-\beta\langle y,w\rangle w = \pm\|y\|e_j
\end{align}$$
Is it possible to use these two routines along with other operations to define a new routine
$$
h_{m+n}\left(i,\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right) = (\gamma,u)\textrm{ where } \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}-\gamma\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}u_x\\u_y\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle \begin{bmatrix}u_x\\u_y\end{bmatrix} = \pm \sqrt{\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2}e_i?
$$
The reason for this request is that I have a situation where the memory for $x$ and $y$ are stored somewhat differently.  It's not particularly convenient to define a new routine to work on the product specifically, so it would be nice to bootstrap the reflector from existing routines.  Thanks for the help.
